# segmentation fault linux c++

Tags: multithreading, memory-management

I have two processes communicating with the memory through a single /dev/mem descriptor. Can there be segmentation fault errors in such a case? If yes, are there any options for simultaneous memory access by two threads? (The addresses used by the threads are different.)

I tried using mutexes, but the segmentation fault error still occurs.

unique_lock lock(memory_access_mtx);
then lock.unlock();

here is the sample of the code

```
#include "MemoryManager.hpp"

#include <chrono>
#include <netinet/ether.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <netinet/udp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include "shared_ptr.hpp" 
#include <fstream>
#include <mutex>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <csignal>


using namespace std;

mutex memory_access_mtx;

Parser parser;
u8 dvb_trx_enable;

void rx_data_raw()
{
    ofstream file("raw_log.txt", ios::binary | ios::app); 
    while(true){
         //Прием данных из DMA
         
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(memory_access_mtx);
        if(MemoryManager::instance()->dma_read_finish_raw())
        {
            pair<shared_ptr_arr<char>,uint32_t> packet = MemoryManager::instance()->get_raw();
            lock.unlock();
            if (packet.second>0)
            {
                file.write(packet.first.get(), packet.second); 
                file.flush();      
            }   
            
        }else{
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    file.close();  
}

void rx_data_packet()
{
    ofstream file("packet_log.txt", ios::binary | ios::app); 
    while(true){
         //Прием данных из DMA
         
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(memory_access_mtx);
        if(MemoryManager::instance()->dma_read_finish_packet())
        {
            
            pair<shared_ptr_arr<char>,uint32_t> packet = MemoryManager::instance()->get_packet();
            lock.unlock();
        
            if (packet.second>0)
            {
                file.write(packet.first.get(), packet.second); 
                file.write("\r\n",2);  
                file.flush();      
            }
            
     
        }else{
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    file.close(); 
}

void printStackTrace() {
    const int max_frames = 20;
    void* callstack[max_frames];
    int frame_count = backtrace(callstack, max_frames);
    char** symbols = backtrace_symbols(callstack, frame_count);

    std::cout << "Stack trace:" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < frame_count; i++) {
        std::cout << symbols[i] << std::endl;
    }

    free(symbols);
}
void segfaultHandler(int signal) {
    std::cerr << "Segmentation fault occurred!" << std::endl;
    printStackTrace();
    exit(signal);
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGSEGV, segfaultHandler);
    MemoryManager::instance()->init_dma();
    NetPacketManager::instance()->init(); 
    MemoryManager::instance()->dma_begin_read_packet();
    MemoryManager::instance()->dma_begin_read_raw();
    
    MemoryManager::instance()->set_rolloff(0);
    thread rx_thread_packet(rx_data_packet);
    thread rx_thread_raw(rx_data_raw);  
    
    printf("main started\n");
    rx_thread_packet.join();
    rx_thread_raw.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe its important that the data to DMA pushed from the PL part. I use Xilinx FPGA

Comment: If a mutex doesn't solve it then simultaneous access is not what is causing the segmentation fault.

Comment: Pretty much any kind of undefined behavior can result in a segmentation fault.  You'll need to post some code that people can compile and run to reproduce the problem, if you want anyone to be able to provide more detail than that.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I've posted the code. But noone can compile it because of DMA and PL part of the project.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah what else can cause this problem?

Comment: I think one problem is that the `std::mutex` class only works within the scope of a single process; since each process has a separate memory-space, the `mutex` in your first process is not the same mutex as the `mutex` in your second process, so locking it has no effect on the other process's behavior and is therefore equivalent to not using mutexes at all.  You'll probably want to use something else like a semaphore instead:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700889/c-mutex-shared-between-processes

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I used threads instead of process, so I thought that threads share the memory between each other. Ok I will check it.

Comment: A `std::mutex` will work for threads in the same process.  Your question starts with the words `I have two processes`, however.